# No space between vertical rule and image

Tags: beamer, spacing, graphics, xetex, miktex

I want to design a titlepage for a beamer presentation (XeLaTeX, Miktex 2.9-64, Win7-64) and need to reduce the space between a rule and a graphic to 0.

My code:

```
\setbeamertemplate{background}
{\hspace{0.6\paperwidth}
\rule{0.1cm}{\paperheight}
\includegraphics[width=0.4\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{mypicture}}
```

My result:

[image: myresults]

In the image above, the space I want gone is marked in red.
What do I need to do?

Comment: Add a `%` after `\rule{0.1cm}{\paperheight}`. Edit: see questions linked to in http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/2429/586

Comment: I'd add a `%` also after `\hspace{0.6\paperwidth}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have spurious spaces and, moreover, the construction will be wider than `\paperwidth`.

```
\setbeamertemplate{background}
  {\hspace{0.6\paperwidth}%
   \hspace{-0.1cm}%
   \rule{0.1cm}{\paperheight}%
   \includegraphics[width=0.4\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{mypicture}}
```

The `%` mask off the end-of-line which would count as an interword space; the negative `\hspace` command compensates for the rule width.